# r: Extracting residuals of regressed data with different dimensions

Tags: r

I am running 500 linear regressions with a different dependent variable each time, but the same independent variables, using the following loop:

```
for(j in 1:500) {
lmj <- lm(formula = df[, j] ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
coeff[j,] <- t(lmj$coefficients)
}
```

However the all columns of df have different ‘start’ and ‘end’ times, e.g.

```
> df[,1]
[1]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[9]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[17]        NA        NA -12.56643   2.90788 -15.80776  10.35763  18.22261  -8.33948
[25] -11.92777   3.35641  -9.13571 -27.46489 -14.18712  -3.75335   3.60028  -0.64753
[33]   1.07798  12.67291   8.83168   2.20233  11.13526   8.75306

> df[,2]
[1]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        4.59821
[9]        1.80505   0.88652   1.05448  -7.39130  -0.46957 -5.85455   7.66825  -3.12985
[17]        -6.58715   -9.43875        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[25]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA      
[33]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

(Note all observations of the dependent variables are consecutive, and there are no NA values in either x1 or x2, i.e. x1 and x2 are both (38x1) vectors. Incidentally, x1 and x2 are the 501st and 502nd columns of df).

How can I save the residuals from each of these 500 regressions?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to do, but I'd define `coef <- resid <- vector('list', 500)` before the loop, and then `coef[[j]] <- lmj$coefficients; resid[[j]] <- lmj$residuals` within the loop. Or else something like this: `lapply(1:500, function(i) { lmj <- lm(df[, i] ~ x1 + x2, data = df); list(coef=lmj$coefficients, resid=lmj$residuals) })`